# How to keep a Wordpress site synchronized between two servers?

Tags: customization, backup

I have a WordPress site running in a dedicated server in hosting A and I would like to keep it synchronized with a copy in another hosting server for fail over protection. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

I've been doing this successfully with csync and an NDB cluster for years...

Re other solutions:

- rsync works too, albeit slower. (Much, much slower; slow enough to rule out any file-based caching.)
- InnoDB/MyIsam master/slave works too, with HyperDB. *But*, you'll end up with a need to manage other stuff, namely auto-increments on write servers, if you need multiple write servers. (NDB is master/master, whereas InooDB or MyISAM cluster are designed and optimized for master/slave setups.)

Comment: You don't happen to have exactly how to do this written up anywhere?

Comment: csync is only for the files, not the database, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can mirror the database and the file-system. For File-system you can use rsync, and for the database, for example that level ;) http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/

Answer (score 0):

This should maybe be handled on a lower level. Have your webserver run on a virtual machine and distribute the container. They call this "cloud" nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Doing MySQL replication isn't the easiest thing in the world,, and requires another server somewhere.

I'd be tempted by something like VaultPress (http://vaultpress.com/features/), even if it doesn't provide true hot stand-by failover.